# VBS won't modify registry

Tags: vbscript, registry

I am writing a vbscript that I need to modify several registry entries. The issue is that after Chrome or Firefox is removed from one of our computers you can no longer open links outside of the web browser. This is because the computer is still treating the removed browser as the default. I have several other registry modifications that are working but when I run the script it will not make changes to the following registry keys:

```
    'does not work
    strRoot = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\open\command\ddeexec\"
    wShell.RegWrite strRoot,"" & Chr(34) & "%1" & Chr(34) & ",,-1,0,,,,"
    'does not work
    strRoot = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\open\command\ddeexec\NoActivateHandler"
    wShell.RegWrite strRoot,""
    'does not work
    strRoot = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\open\command\ddeexec\Application\"
    wShell.RegWrite strRoot,"IExplore"
    'does not work
    strRoot = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\open\command\ddeexec\Topic\"
    wShell.RegWrite strRoot,"WWW_OpenURL"
```

This also needs to be applied to the "HTTP" key in the same path and likewise nothing within the "ddeexec" folder can be changed. I don't believe it's a permissions issue however because I can go into regedit and change it manually with no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\open\ddeexec\
```

instead of

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\open\command\ddeexec\
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this script locally or remotely?  Does the machine have any antivirus running?  Which version of Windows are you using?

Registry permissions for script access can be different than that of the local user account.  Namely this means that having success changing a registry key with Registry Editor does not necessarily mean that you will be able to do it from a script.

As an aside, opening any remaining browser on this system should prompt the user to make it their default browser.  If they choose to allow that, it will reset all of these settings for you.

Comment: The script is designed to be run remotely under the system account however the results are the same even if I just run it with my own credentials on my own machine.

The machines that this would be used for are all Windows XP SP3 32bit. They all have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed. Opening IE does not prompt to make the default due to group policy restrictions. I think whoever imaged these was thinking that restricting that setting in IE would prevent other browsers from becoming the default but it does not.